# str_replace() não funcionando corretamente com arrays geradas

Tags: php

Segue o código:

```
$minu = range("a", "z");
$maiu = range("A", "Z");

$letras = array_merge($minu, $maiu);

$minusculas = array_merge($minu, $maiu);
```

Ao fazer um `str_replace($Lminusculas, $Lmaiusculas, "TesteSimples");` o seguinte é retornado:

> lerveSimvses

E, ao fazer um `str_replace($Lmaiusculas, $Lminusculas, "lerveSimvses");` o seguinte é retornado:

> TistERUephes

Porém, eu queria que ao fazer o segundo `str_replace()` a *string* voltasse ao estado inicial *TesteSimples*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi direito, a sua intenção com o código é “criptografar” a string, trocando ‘A’ e ‘Z’, ‘B’ e ‘Y’, …? Se sim, o problema é que a [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php) faz as substituições “em ordem”; eu acho que é mais semântico usar [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtr.php), que faz o que você quer e opera sobre cada byte individualmente, e por isso provavelmente é mais eficiente:

```
<?php

$antes = implode(array_merge(range('a', 'z'), range('A', 'Z')));
$depois = implode(array_merge(range('z', 'a'), range('Z', 'A')));

echo strtr('Stack Overflow', $antes, $depois) . "\n";
echo strtr('Hgzxp Leviuold', $antes, $depois) . "\n";

?>
```

Comment: (naturalmente, essa “criptografia” vai engasgar se a string tiver caracteres acentuados)

Comment: Não terá caracteres acentuados, somente minusculos e maiusculos, @ctgpi. Em relação à sua resposta, minha intenção é sim "criptografar" a string. Mudei de `str_replace` para `strtr` porém nem "criptografa" e nem "descriptografa". Lembrando que meu código continua o mesmo da pergunta, apenas substitui as funções (`str_replace` por `strtr`).

Comment: A `strtr` com três parâmetros aceita strings, não arrays, e a ordem dos parâmetros é diferente; você vai ter que `implode`ir os arrays antes de chamar a `strtr`, que nem eu fiz no meu código.

Comment: Ah, era isso mesmo! Faltava o `implode`, funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado!